# In python, how to add new markers to boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I have used pandas's boxplot function to create a boxplot, then I would like to add the mean/97.5%/2.5% quantiles of each column to the boxplot.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])
    df.boxplot(return_type='axes')
```

In short, I want to have additional markers or points in the plot to give more statistic illustrations. I am capable of adding arbitrary points to an R plot; but for python, I cannot figure out how. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scatter` so as to make points:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shape = (100,2)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(*shape), columns=['x', 'y'])
df.boxplot(return_type='axes')

q975 = df.quantile(0.975)
q025 = df.quantile(0.025)
mean = df.mean()

plt.scatter(range(1,shape[1]+1), q975, c='m', label='Q_97.5')
plt.scatter(range(1,shape[1]+1), q025, c='r', label='Q_2.5')
plt.scatter(range(1,shape[1]+1), mean, c='k', label='Mean')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I need.